# How to find out item is created in recycler view for the first time?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view and I want to find out if an item is created in recycler view for the first time or not?

Is there an event handler for it?

Note: I know how to implement it with flag, but I'm looking for another approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want this? To my mind it seems like there is not a good reason to know this information, a ViewHolder should be independent from that knowledge.

Nothing is provided for this by [RecyclerView.Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html) , the only callbacks are to manage the [ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html) instances, which can be recycled and so any particular instance wouldn't know if it is the first instance or not.

You could store a flag in your data model and access it when you set up the ViewHolder in `onBindViewHolder`, as you seem to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can ovveride onViewAttachedToWindow(holder: ViewHolder) in your recycler adapter. sample code like this:

```
private var isFirstChildAttached = false // single fire
override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(holder: ViewHolder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder)
    holder.pageView.registerTopLevelTouchListener()


    if (!isFirstChildAttached) {
        isFirstChildAttached = true
        checkAndFirePageDimen(holder.itemView)
    }
}

private fun checkAndFirePageDimen(itemView: View){
    itemView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            itemView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
            pagerCallback.onFirstItemAttachedToPager(itemView)
        }
    })
}
```

"checkAndFirePageDimen" helps you for reliable itemView size.